# What does the Queue Standard Library Interface of Chisel 3 synthesizes to?

Tags: riscv, chisel

There are brief definitions of `Queue` and other Standard Library Interfaces of Chisel (`Decoupled`, `Valid`, etc) in the [Cheat-Sheet](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/chisel-cheatsheet.pdf) and a bit more detail in the [Chisel Manual](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/chisel-manual.pdf). I also found these two answers here at StackOverflow - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380823/what-does-queue-function-do-in-chisel?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129440/8929685).

However, neither of these resources explains in the plastic way - and I feel that would help me better understand the purpose of these Interfaces - what do these lines of code synthesize to - what do they look like in actual hardware?

For example, here is a snippet of the FPU code from the package [HardFloat](https://github.com/ucb-bar/berkeley-hardfloat):

`val input = Decoupled(new DivRecFN_io(expWidth, sigWidth)).flip`

where `DivRecFN_io` is a class as follows:

`class DivRecFN_io(expWidth: Int, sigWidth: Int) extends Bundle {
    val a = ...
    val b = ...
    val ...
    ...
}`

What exactly is achieved with the line containing `Decouple`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it looks like in actual hardware:

The default Chisel util Queue is a standard [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#/media/File:Circular_Buffer_Animation.gif) implementation. This means it has a series of registers with an enqueue and dequeue pointer, that move as a result of operations on the queue, checked for fullness and emptiness.

Comment: @collins, thanks, this answers my question, I just thought to add a nice [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#/media/File:Circular_Buffer_Animation.gif) from Wikipedia, for representation completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Decoupled wires a DivRecFN Bundle to field named bits and adds ready and valid signals that are typically used to manage flow control for Modules that do not return results within a single cycle. By default DecoupledIO's data fields would be `Output`.  The flip at the end of the line would convert that to `Input`. Considering a module **C** which contains the `val input` and a module **P** that uses an instance of Module(**C**), The module **C** would be *consuming* the data in the Bundle, the parent of this module **P** would be producing the data placed in the Bundle. **C** would assert `ready` to indicate it is ready for data, and would read/use that data when `valid` is asserted by **P**.
The fields in the decoupled Bundle would be

```
input.ready
input.valid
input.bits.a
input.bits.b
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the great interpretation. Could you, please, be more specific when you write "module declaring it" - do you mean the one containing the the `val input`? Because, that `val input` is again a part of another `Bundle` (called `io`) used in a different `Module` (called `ValExec_DivSqrtRecFN_small_div`). Also, where did you find that field titled `bits` - or it comes from the fact that `a` and `b` are of type `Bits`?

Comment: In the statement val input = Decoupled(new DivRecFN_io(expWidth, sigWidth)).flip, input is a Bundle containing ready, valid and bits fields.  The bits field contains the the bundle passed to the Decoupled(), in this case new DivRecFN. I have edited the answer to try and make it clear which module I am talking about.